# This 'object' might be unmatched

Tags: list, object, ocaml

I am trying sum up inside a tuple using matching pattern. Here is what I have done

```
let rec sum = function
  | [] -> (0,0,0,0)
  | obj::rest -> let (cc, cd, cr, ca) = sum rest in
      (obj#method1 + cc, obj#method2 + cd
       obj#method3 + cr, obj#method4 + ca) in
```

This recursive function can take a list of objects and return a tuple like `(12893, 82382, 182942, 348934)`

I got the error `This 'object' might be unmatched`. What is a good workaround for that issue?

**UPDATE**

```
  method the_method (pays:string) =
    
    let obj_list = self#return_data_country
    let rec sum = function
      | [] -> (0,0,0,0)
      | obj::rest -> let (cc, cd, cr, ca) = sum rest in
          (obj#method1 + cc, obj#method2 + cd
           obj#method3 + cr, obj#method4 + ca) in 
    
    let sum_cc, sum_cd, sum_cr, sum_ca = sum obj_list in
    let basic_info = (nth obj_list 0) in

    ("\nCountry : " ^ basic_info#method5 ^ "\n" ^
     "UPDATE: " ^ basic_info#method6 ^ "\n" ^
     "CC: " ^ string_of_int sum_cc ^ "\n" ^
     "CD: " ^ string_of_int sum_cd ^ "\n" ^
     "CR: " ^ string_of_int sum_cr ^ "\n" ^
     "CA: " ^ string_of_int sum_ca ^ "\n" ^)
```

Comment: Can you post the full code? The error doesn't seem to arise from the sample shown here.

Answer (score 1):

This error message is talking about the literal token `object`. You have an `object` with no matching `end`. As @Yawar says, the error isn't in the lines you show here.

**Update**

If this copy/paste is accurate, you have this:

```
 "CA: " ^ string_of_int sum_ca ^ "\n" ^)
```

There's a strange `^` operator at the end of the string expression.

Comment: I still don't see the `object` token that the compiler is telling you about. Do you have an `end` at tne end of your class definition? Or do you maybe have an extra `end` that doesn't belong?

Answer (score 1):

In your code I see a `self` value which is never defined in the snippet you gave us.

I think somewhere before you are defining an object as something like `let blabla = object(self)` and you forgot to close if with the `end` keyword.